# Rating is temporarily unavailable - Error in FEDEX

Tags: php, soap, fedex

I am integrating the FEDEX through SOAP webservice in php on my project.
But now i am getting this error for last 2 days. Is this error occuring due to FEDEX or any other error in coding/data ? The below is the response i am getting when using the FEDEX Webservice.

**Error returned in processing transaction**

**Severity: FAILURE**

**Source: crs**

**Code: 7**

**Message: Rating is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.**

**LocalizedMessage: Rating is temporarily unavailable, please try again later.**

Answer (score 2):

Like tribulant mentioned try using production credentials. I did has the same issue with test server ans was able to resolve it through production credentials

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here using test credentials.
I wonder what the problem is and if they will fix it.

It seems like the live/production server is online and working though (if you have production credentials). The URL for SOAP should be https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate (note that "wsbeta" is changed to "ws")