# FedEx Rate Request returns "Rating is temporarily unavailable, please try again later."

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, soap, fedex

I am working on FedEx integrations using testing credentials and the Rate Service has been returning the message "Rating is temporarily unavailable, please try again later." other services i.e. Ship, Validate etc seem to be working fine.

It was working fine a couple of days ago now every time I am getting the same response.
I am not sure if it is something to do with my code or FedEx service is down.

I cannot find anything to check weather their service is down.

Response Before:

[image]

Response Now:

[image]

Comment: I think the phrasing of that error message very clearly indicates that this is a problem on their end.

Comment: @CBroe I agree but I've been checking their website and other platforms and over there it says that the service is running fine.

Comment: @CBroe I looked for announcements [here](https://www.fedex.com/en-us/developer/announcements.html) and checked on [shipping api monitor](https://www.shippingapimonitor.com/history.html?api=fedex)

Comment: The first one appears to be for general functionality change announcements, and the second one is just an external service that covers whether the API works in general (is it “down” or “up”) – neither of those are what would I consider an actual indicator _not_ to trust what the error message is saying.

Comment: @CBroe Is there any other way to find out if the service is down? or do I need another account ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a problem with fedex Rating service and they are recommending using production credentials for the Rate service.

I got a response from FedEx via email saying that everyone is facing the same problem as mine and the development team is looking into the issue.

Comment: And seems like they have this problem for quite some time, found the same solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156258/rating-is-temporarily-unavailable-error-in-fedex/11172555#11172555)

Comment: Well they haven't fixed it.  It was working before for me and now it is failing with this exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the same problem with production credentials.

In my case, the issue as the **ShipTimestamp** which was three months old.

By setting it to match current datetime, I got no issue.